# Where can I heal myself in Knightfall 2?

Tags: knightfall-2

In Knightfall 2, I just reached the 2nd Inn. Are there more places that I can heal myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as complained about by some people, the only two places to heal yourself are Home Tavern and Snowy Tavern.

You can also heal yourself with food and potions in dungeons though, and leveling up heals you the amount that your HP increases.